# Android sending captured image rotates 90 degree in some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-image, android-camera-intent

I am working on an Android application. In my app I have to capture a image and send that image to server. In some device the captured image posted in server with 90 degree rotation. I searched in stackoverflow and some other sites for a fix. I got solutions ..I used all them For eg:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();


File imageFile = new File(selectedImage.toString());
ExifInterface exif;
try {
exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

switch(orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:

rotate=90;

    break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

    rotate=180;
 break;
            }
```

But unfortunately I am getting orientation 0 always in every device. Even in the 90 degree rotated image devices.

Please help to fix my issue friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by using the following code.

```
private int getImageOrientation(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
        rotate=orientation;
        System.out.println("orientation==="+orientation);
        cursor.close();
        return orientation;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your response dear friends...

Answer (score 1):

You use:

```
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

So, you send defaultValue ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL. Maybe your exif hasn't attribute TAG_ORIENTATION (or ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED) and you get default value?

Try:

```
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
```

and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your images are rotated at 270 degrees
add this to your switch statement

```
switch(orientation) 
{
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
rotate=90;

break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:

rotate=180;
break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

rotate=270;
break;
}
```